# Ubuntu 23.04 - While compiling a program (gpx2video), the linker gives me various errors with libraries (incompatible, not found,...)

Tags: compiling, 23.04

While compiling a program (gpx2video), the linker gives me various errors with libraries (incompatible, not found)

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
   The C compiler

     "/usr/bin/cc"

   is not able to compile a simple test program.

   It fails with the following output:

     Change Dir: /media/DATA_G_Ext4/Gopro/gpx2video/gpx2video/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-lKh0gb
    
     Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_f5b91/fast && /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/build
     gmake[1]: entry into directory «/media/DATI_G_Ext4/Gopro/gpx2video/gpx2video/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-lKh0gb»
     Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
     /usr/bin/cc -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /media/DATA_G_Ext4/Gopro/gpx2video/gpx2video/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-lKh0gb/testCCompiler.c
     Linking C executable cmTC_f5b91
     /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
     /usr/bin/cc -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_f5b91
     /usr/local/bin/ld: warning: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
     /usr/local/bin/ld: warning: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0008002
     /usr/local/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
     /usr/local/bin/ld: skipped incompatible /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 when searching for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     /usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
     /usr/local/bin/ld: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unknown type [0x13] section `.relr.dyn'
     /usr/local/bin/ld: skipped incompatible /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 when searching for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     /usr/local/bin/ld: cannot find /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
     gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_f5b91.dir/build.make:99: cmTC_f5b91] Error 1
     gmake[1]: output from directory «/media/DATA_G_Ext4/Gopro/gpx2video/gpx2video/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-lKh0gb»
     gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_f5b91/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like you have a non-compatible `ld` program in `/usr/local` (which is found first, due to `$PATH` order) - everything in the standard Ubuntu toolchain would be in `/usr`

Comment: So, what can I do? I had already reinstalled binutils

Comment: There's a bunch of things you can try  - (1) defining your `PATH` such that `/usr/bin` precedes `/usr/local/bin` (2) using the available `CMAKE` variables to specify the correct linker e.g. you could try re-running `cmake` with `-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fuse-ld=/usr/bin/ld"` or (3) removing the incompatible toolchain (if it serves no purpose). See for example [CMake: use a custom linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867745/cmake-use-a-custom-linker).

Comment: Tried both of your suggested solutions to no avail. The error is always there.